# gdb backtrace is not showing full stack-trace with main()

Tags: c++, gdb

I am using [Xalan library](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/apiDocs/index.html). My program is crashing somewhere inside Xalan calls. I would like to see a full stack-trace from main() all the way to crash point. I am using the following command line to compile

```
g++ -o program.out -g -O0 -lxalan-c myprogram.out
```

I am using 'backtrace full' command and getting the following output

```
 #0  0xb79313b4 in xalanc_1_11::XPath::findRoot(xalanc_1_11::XPathExecutionContext&,    xalanc_1_11::XalanNode*, int const*, int, xalanc_1_11::MutableNodeRefList&) const () from     /usr/lib/libxalan-c.so.111
No symbol table info available.
#1  0xb793afa9 in xalanc_1_11::XPath::step(xalanc_1_11::XPathExecutionContext&, xalanc_1_11::XalanNode*, int const*, xalanc_1_11::MutableNodeRefList&) const
() from /usr/lib/libxalan-c.so.111
No symbol table info available.
#2  0xb793d350 in xalanc_1_11::XPath::locationPath(xalanc_1_11::XalanNode*, int const*,  xalanc_1_11::XPathExecutionContext&) const ()
from /usr/lib/libxalan-c.so.111
No symbol table info available.
#3  0xb7937d22 in xalanc_1_11::XPath::executeMore(xalanc_1_11::XalanNode*, int const*,  xalanc_1_11::XPathExecutionContext&) const ()
from /usr/lib/libxalan-c.so.111
 No symbol table info available.
 #4  0xbffff02c in ?? ()
 No symbol table info available.
```

The above stack-trace is obviously not showing the full stack-trace starting from main(), what am I missing ?

There is only one thread running, here is the output of show threads

```
  Id   Target Id         Frame
 * 1    Thread 0xb6f79980 (LWP 8888) "xmltest.out" 0xb79313b4 in xalanc_1_11::XPath::findRoot(xalanc_1_11::XPathExecutionContext&, xalanc_1_11::XalanNode*, int const*, int, xalanc_1_11::MutableNodeRefList&) const () from /usr/lib/libxalan-c.so.111
```

Comment: Can it be that you're using Xalan from a global class that can be instantiated before main()?

Comment: Xalan is used inside a class that I wrote yes, but its being instantiated in the stack of main()

Comment: Then, I would bet that the stack has been corrupted in some way and, because of this, you can't see calling functions in the backtrace. Although `valgrind` is not very strong on stack corruptions, maybe, you can use it to get more information.

Comment: Whats valgrind ? A separate tool like gdb ? Where can I install it ? Does it have a zypper/rpm package for opensuse ?

Comment: Yes, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is a very strong debugging tool. If you're using Linux, you will find it in your distribution's package repository.

Comment: Looks like missing symbol table is the root problem. Multiple other answers about that

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Initially I though the same but, from the building code line, is clear that `-g` option is used. Can it be a problem of incompatibility versions between g++ and gdb? fahadash, can you, please, provide gdb and g++ versions?

Comment: gdb version: GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (7.5.1-2.1.1)
g++ version: g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012]

Comment: -g is used for the main, but not necessarily for the libxalan

Comment: Rebuild libxalan-c with -g and you should see backtraces through it.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Post your comment as an answer, I will set it as answer to my question.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Well, initially, from backtrace, it seems that libxalan-c already has debug info but, I think, is a good suggestion to build it again with `-g` just in case. On the other hand, fahadash, when you run the application with `gdb` doesn't it suggest you to use `file` command?

Comment: Please, add output of `info shared` to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebuild libxalan-c with -g and you should see backtraces through it.

As mentioned in the comments -ggdb or -ggdb3 may be needed instead of -g for some targets.

Comment: You appear to believe that `-g` is required for proper backtrace, which is false. If rebuilding with `-g` helps at all, it will only do so by accident.

Comment: "Rebuilding xalan with symbols" helped me. Xalan had a parameter for their configure script for debug symbol generation. Thank you

Comment: @EmployedRussian You might be right, its -ggdb or -ggdb3 for full info.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the stack has been corrupted and, because of this, you can't see backtrace's origin.

Although [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is not very strong on stack corruptions, you can use it to get more information. If you're using Linux, you will find it in your distribution's development package repository.